# How to get the name of the "top" class in a class cluster?

Tags: objective-c, class, types, class-cluster

**Setup:**

I have data coming in via JSON.

Using NSJSONSerialization I convert the JSON to an object.

A number value in JSON comes in Objective-C as several different possible class types:

(`NSNumber, NSDecimalNumber or __NSCFNumber`) - all of those are in the class cluster under `NSNumber`.

---

**Problem:**

1) I need a way to get the class cluster "umbrella" class - `NSNumber`, when I have a value of any of the types `NSNumber, NSDecimalNumber or __NSCFNumber`.

Same goes for strings. I need a way to get `NSString`, when I have any of these: `NSString, NSMutableString, __NSCFString, __NSCFConstantString`.

2) It could work also if I could get by code a list of all classes in the NSString cluster for example. Then I can build dynamically at run-time a list, and be sure it is complete.

---

**What I have so far:**

So far I couldn't come up with a sane way to do that. So I have a list of allowed types, but I'm afraid it might not be complete + it doesn't feel like the greatest solution there is.

Code:
https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModel.m#L45

Comment: Also note that `NSCFBoolean` is a subclass of `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
id object = // obtain the object somehow

Class cls = Nil; // for now

// property list types, roughly equivalent to JSON's fundamental types
NSArray *classes = @[[NSString class], [NSNumber class], [NSArray class], [NSDictionary class], [NSData class], [NSDate class]];

Class c;
for (c in classes) {
    if ([object isKintOfClass:c]) {
        cls = c;
        break;
    }
}
```

you can extend the list by adding other classes to the `classes` array. In the end, `cls` will contain the class cluster of which `object` is an instance, or `Nil` if it isn't an instance of either one.

Comment: This works for Core Foundation classes. Keep in mind that there might be more Class Clusters out there.

Comment: @Berik I didn't state/imply this is universal, nor did OP's problem need it to be so.